# Configuring App Gateway to redirect response path

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have setup an azure app gateway with path based routing and two back end pools pointing at app services.

I have setup www.mywebsite.com/site1 and www.mywebsite.com/site2

If you access www.mywebsite.com/site1 the site loads but site resources 404.  Resources are pointing at www.mywebsite.com/images/logo.jpg rather than www.mywebsite.com/site1/images/logo.jpg.

I assume I need to use an app gateway url rewrite rule to rewrite the response to point to the correct path.  Is that correct? and if so how do I do this?

Comment: Running into this issue as well. Were you able to find a solution that worked?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure application gateway for URL path `www.mywebsite.com/site1` like this:

**Add a Path-based routing rule**

```
Path              /site1/*
Target name       targentname1
HTTP settings     httpsetting1
backend target    backendpool1
```

Override backend path with `/images/` in the httpsetting1.

[image]

Hope this works.